# sql - double where condition is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT id as id,status as status,'movie-name' as 'key',
moviename as value,poster as cover 
FROM movie 
WHERE id='$movieid' AND status='Coming Soon' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
```

does not seems to work. If I delete `AND status='Coming Soon'` it works.

Comment: wrap off quotes form column name at `'movie-name' as 'key'` instead use backtick

Comment: Saty, what do you mean by wrap off?

Comment: This is not a problem of WHERE condition. Please share the error which you are getting when running this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backtic and not single quote for movie-name and key  and remove alias for status (because this could create problem in where)

```
 $sql3 =  "SELECT DISTINCT id ,status ,`movie-name`  as `key`,
             moviename as value,poster as cover 
           FROM movie 
           WHERE id='$movieid' 
           AND status='Coming Soon' 
           ORDER BY id DESC 
           LIMIT 6";
```

if movie-name is a name and not a column  use single quote for select the literal  value but remember of don't use improper alias like status in where condition

```
 $sql3 =  "SELECT DISTINCT id ,status ,'movie-name'  as `key`,
             moviename as value,poster as cover 
           FROM movie 
           WHERE id='$movieid' 
           AND status='Coming Soon' 
           ORDER BY id DESC 
           LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: what if `movie-name` is not column??

Comment: I have update the answer but the real problem is related to the improper use of alias